# PHP Fatal error with external XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a php script which loads an xml file for our shoprating.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.kiyoh.nl/xml/recent_company_reviews.xml?xxxxx");

echo "<span itemprop='rating' itemscope itemtype='https://data-vocabulary.org/Rating'>Beoordeling: <span itemprop='average'>";
 foreach($xml->children() as $average)
{
echo $average->total_score;
}
echo "</span>/<span itemprop='best'>10</span></span>";
echo " - <span itemprop='votes'>";
foreach($xml->children() as $total_review)
{
    echo $total_review->total_reviews;
}
echo "</span> stemmen";
?>
```

Sometimes we get a fatal error on the line

```
foreach($xml->children() as $average)
```

I think it has something to do that the xml files can't be accessed.
But this script is at the top opf the page, so the rest isn't downloaded anymore.

Is there a way that it can be bypassed? When it can't connect? So the site will be allways visible?

UPDATE 15-08-2014
I use this script to read out my rating at a external site.
Sometimes i can't access the external site ... but when that happens my site gives a fatal error.

What should the code be to auto pass this script is not available?

Comment: You shouldn't depend on a XML file from an other website. What if the structure is going to change?

Comment: Have you try foreach($xml as $average) and have you got content in $xml variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.kiyoh.nl/xml/recent_company_reviews.xml?xxxxx");
if (! empty($xml)) {
  //Your code here

} else {
   Echo "There is something wrong getting my xml file. Please try again later";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a simple if statement that checks IF $xml is not empty. :) So if you couldn't read the file the page will still load, but without the xml functionality.
Best of luck!

Comment: Should it be like this: `if(!empty($xml)) { } else {echo "<span ... rest of the code}`

Comment: Check if simplexml_load_file() returns empty or FALSE when you can't fetch the file so you know what you check for. If it returns false you can't check with empty and it will always go to the else statement.